# Github Action and ROS

Tags: ros, github-actions

I have a (private) repo where I am now just trying to save the list of `ros` msgs on a file. I have the following `main.yml` file in `.github/workflows/`:

```
name: ROS kinetic CI
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-16.04
    container: ros:kinetic
    services: 
      ros: 
        image: ros
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Save all ros msgs into a file
        run: rosmsg list > ros_msg_list.txt
```

When the job runs, it fails on that job that calls `rosmsg` with the error:

```
Run rosmsg list > ros_msg_list.txt
  rosmsg list > ros_msg_list.txt
  shell: sh -e {0}
/__w/_temp/a3af4a58-e885-4af2-ab31-016bd46cd1d5.sh: 1: /__w/_temp/a3af4a58-e885-4af2-ab31-016bd46cd1d5.sh: rosmsg: not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

What am I missing here? I run locally `docker run -it ros:kinetic bash` and inside the container I can directly run `rosmsg show` without any issues.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should use checkout v2; and the Actions runner doesn't know what `rosmsg` is; if it's not in the PATH, you have to use the absolute path to the executable.

Comment: I tried adding it to PATH but still it didn't work. I updated the question to have the things I tried. I also tried the commented lines. Even if I add `/opt/ros/kinetic/bin` to the PATH (which doesn't add it: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`) or use the full path to `rosmsg` the issue remains.

Comment: That's not how you modify `PATH` in a job, see the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-system-path)

Comment: Perfect, now `/opt/ros/kinetic/bin` is in `PATH`. However the problem still remains. Either I call just `rosmsg` or with the absolute path I still cannot list the ros msgs...

Comment: Oooh, I'm sorry, I didn't look properly. You're running a job with a [service container](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/about-service-containers) – did you look at those docs?

Comment: Yes, I was missing the `service` part to have the `ros` image. I updated the `.yml` (edited the question). However, I don't quite get how to run `rosmg` on the container and get the output of it.